# why thread run later than i call it even i try many times

Tags: android

i have class extends thread it get number of rows in the database. on  oncreate method i start the extends class and use after that method name setupListView() that is use the output of the thread class but the problem is that i found the method run before the thread class . i don't know how

thread class

```
  public class array1 extends Thread{

    String page="";


    public void run(){

        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.168.43.16/marche/arraysize.php");   
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
        response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
         page = sb.toString();

         String s11[]=  page.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
         s2=Integer.parseInt(s11[0]);
         System.out.println(s2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        if (in != null) {
        try {
        in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    }

    }



}
```

oncreate

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    array1 www=new array1(); 
    www.start();
    Sendfeed1 pro1=new Sendfeed1();
    pro1.start();      
    Sendfeed pro=new Sendfeed();
    pro.start();
    mSmoothInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
    mMinHeaderTranslation = -mHeaderHeight + getActionBarHeight();



    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mHeader = findViewById(R.id.header);
    mHeaderPicture = (KenBurnsView) findViewById(R.id.header_picture);
    mHeaderPicture.setResourceIds(R.drawable.picture0, R.drawable.picture1);
    mHeaderLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_logo);


    mActionBarTitleColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar_title_color);

    mSpannableString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.noboringactionbar_title));
    mAlphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(mActionBarTitleColor);

    setupActionBar();
    setupListView();


}
```

Comment: You encountered a thread synchronization issue, i.e. one thread depends on the result of an asynchronously running other thread. You should read up knowledge about basic multithreading (concurrency and parallellism) to understand the issue.

Comment: I recommend reading this book https://pragprog.com/book/pb7con/seven-concurrency-models-in-seven-weeks

Comment: You should use AsynTask or Services that Android framework provides.

Answer (score 1):

The issue are you having is you have 2 threads one the UI thread who create a new one (Array1) when you say www.start(); doesn't means your UI thread will wait for it until ends UI thread continue the execution. Now both are running "parallels" on the CPU. So you have to notify to the UI thread the background task is done. Once the run() method finish just notify it. How to do that you can use a LocalBroadcastManager to deliver onto the UI Thread the result or use a Handler if you want to modify the UI from Array1 thread.

One suggestion also take a look to the AsyncTask class can be helpful for you.

I hope this help.